# How do I prove that this triangle is equilateral?

Tags: geometry

We know that :

- ABCD is a square.
- BGFE is a square.
- AEB is an equilateral triangle.
- AB = 1.

Here is the figure :
[image]
**How can I prove that BCG is equilateral ?**

Comment: BCG is a triangle. Which sides and angles do you know already? Can you see how to work out any others?

Comment: According to given, EB=AB and EB=BG. Also, BC=AB=EB=BG. Not sure how CG would come out but I think proving that $\angle CBG=60^O$ would work.

Comment: @MarkBennet I know CB, BG and... well... I don't find anything else :(

Comment: @MarkBennet Oh ! and if I am not doing a mistake I also know that CBG = 60° (by using some other calculation I did sooner).

Comment: @Shubham Thanks for your advice, I am going to search in this way.

Comment: So can you see that you have an isosceles triangle CBG, so the base angles are equal ...

Comment: @MarkBennet Oh !!!! Thanks a lot ! I just didn't thought to that ! It is always the same thing that is happening to me in mathematics : I don't understand anything and than we tell me the good method to follow, and then it just feels so obvious... but I have some difficulties to find the good methods by myself !

Comment: @MarkBennet Finally it's all right !

Comment: You have BC and BG equal so the angles at C and G are equal. If two sides of a triangle are equal, the angles opposite those sides are equal - use symmetry or the sine rule to prove it.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

$$
|BC| = |AB| = |BE| = |BG|\\
∠EBC = ∠ABC - ∠ABE = 90˚ - 60˚ = 30˚\\
∠CBG = ∠EBG - ∠EBC = 90˚ - 30˚ = 60˚\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

$ABCD$ is a square, so its angles are known. Let's say that the length of its side is the unit. Well, ditto for the other three sides. One of the sides of the square coïncides with a side of the equilateral triangle $ABE$. We know the angles of $ABE$ and its sides, as well.  One side of the square $BEFG$ coïncides with a side of $ABE$, so we know all about $BEFG$, as well. Line segments $CD$ and $EF$ intersect at point $H$. The line $BH$ is obviously an axis of symmetry for the entire figure. Now all you have to do is to match corresponding elements (lines and angles) to reach the proper conclusions.